# Why people experience more jerk or shock sitting in the back seats of a bus?

Tags: automotive-engineering

Those sitting in front and mid part doesn't experience much shock, while those those sitting in back does. Why?

Answer (score 6):

Two reasons:

1. The suspension in the rear of the bus is firmer because it has to carry more load
2. The area behind the wheels of a bus acts as a [third-class lever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lever#Classes_of_levers), amplifying the movement due to roadway bumps.